# #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
insert into order 
    (order_no, product_code, confirmation_date, payment, order_from, 
     return_eligibility, cs_activity, created_date) 
values 
    ('2547', 'DJRN2503', '2016/11/03 14:42', 'Coupon', 'Homeshop18', 
     'Yes', 'Yes', DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 750 MINUTE));
```

My table name is '`order`'. I am not able to run any queries on this table.

I am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (order_no, product_code, confirmation_date, payment, order_from, return_el' at line 1

Can anyone please guide me?

Comment: order is a keyword in MySQL (`ORDER BY`). Pick a different name for your table or use apostrophes when you refer to that table.

Comment: Thank you so much...i got the result :)

Comment: @MartinVerjans: it will be great to post it now as an answer to the question so as Viswanathan marks it as such in order to clear this question from the unanswered queue.

Comment: @nyedidikeke 
 
Juergen already posted this answer... OP needs to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @MartinVerjans: noted, but I'm not the post author and cannot mark any answer as such! Only Viswanathan can.

Answer (score 2):

`order` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks or use a different table name.

```
insert into `order` (...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much...i got the result :)

Comment: @viswanathan Please mark this answer as "Accepted" (the check mark next to the upvote button). So everyone can see your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to be more sure from where you get this table you could always write the name of the database first,  DatabaseName.TableName